# URL Rewrite issue, cfm to .net

Tags: .net, redirect, url-rewriting, coldfusion

I am looking to redirect

```
somewebsite.tld/oldpage.cfm?Query=505050
```

to

```
somewebsite.tld/New?ref=505050
```

I've done the following

In web.config I've added a handler to handle the .cfm request

```
<system.webServer>
 <handlers>
  <add name="ColdFusion" path="*.cfm" verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
 </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

I've added the following ewrite rule but it does not work.

```
<rewrite>
 <rules>
  <rule name="Redirect oldpage.cfm" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="oldpage\\.cfm(\\?(\\w+)=(\\d+))" /> <action type="Redirect" url="New?ref={R:3}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
 </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I was able to use a urlmapping to at least read a request from /View with the following rule.

```
<system.web>
 <urlMappings>
  <add url="~/oldpage.cfm" mappedUrl="~/New" />
 </urlMappings>
</system.web>
```

However this still does not grab the query string.

Comment: not sure why stackoverflow editor added the extra code but the rewrite rule I have is <match url="oldpage\.cfm(\?(\w+)=(\d+))" />

Comment: You cannot match against query string via `<match>`, check `<conditions>` instead. [Here is a related question on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165676/iis-url-rewrite-not-working-with-query-string)