# Adding a "?" using IIS URL Rewrite

Tags: url, redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I need to create an URL rewrite so that when the users type: mydomain.com/test123 the server gets: mydomain.com/?test123.

I tried this:

`<rule name="UF" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="example.com/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/?{R:1}" />
  </rule>`

Comment: check this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165676/iis-url-rewrite-not-working-with-query-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165676/iis-url-rewrite-not-working-with-query-string)

Comment: Also check Mistake 1, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use below url rewrite rule.

```
            <rule name="UF" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/?{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```

Result:

[image]