# Redirect old page to new page usign web.config

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

i need to rewrite the url from old page to new page, an example:
old: https://www.mysite.it/scheda.asp?num=123456
new: https://www.mysite.it/scheda/?num=123456

i've put in web.config the following lines but don't work, when i go to https://www.mysite.it/scheda.asp?num=123456 noting happen, site go to the page without rewrite:

```
  <rule name="scheda-rew" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="scheda.asp(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="scheda/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
  </rule>
```

i try this:

```
<rule name="scheda-rew2" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^scheda\.asp" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="isbn=([0-9]+)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="scheda/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

nothing appen, seem that all change i do haven't effect

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IIS URL Rewrite not working with query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165676/iis-url-rewrite-not-working-with-query-string)

Comment: Thnak you, probabilly i don't understand, but i need to make it work on every page https://www.mysite.it/scheda/?num=\d+ of my new site, but don't work, why?

Comment: @LexLi see the edit

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Learn how the rule works internally, and you probably can then know what to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below rule, if you have any question please let me know:

```
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL2" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^scheda.asp\?([^/]+)/?$" />
       <conditions>
            <add input="{​​​​​​​REQUEST_FILENAME}​​​​​​​" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{​​​​​​​REQUEST_FILENAME}​​​​​​​" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{​​​​​​​REQUEST_URI}​​​​​​​" pattern="^scheda/$" negate="true" />
       </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="scheda/?num=123456" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```